# anyone knows how to create plotly pie chart

Tags: python, plotly-python

I want to create a pie chart with two columns as values and 1 column with labels, dataset image is attack and I want results in males who brought and do not bought car and the same for females. [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E3Nbb.png)

Comment: Check the documentation : https://plotly.com/python/pie-charts/

Comment: this is not i am looking for

Comment: what have you tried? is there a particular piece of code that is not working?